# Jquery cannot encode json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i return this json from my php page but jquery cannot decode it,result is always null.

```
{
    "City": [
        {
            "CityID": "1",
            "CityName": "istanbul"
        },
        {
            "CityID": "2",
            "CityName": "Ankara"
        }
    ]
}
```

Jquery Code:

```
     $.getJSON("handlers/cityhandler.php", function(json){
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
console.log(result[0].City.CityID);
```

Jquery alternate code:

```
$.getJSON("handlers/cityhandler.php", function(json){
            $.each(json, function(i,City){
                    $("#selectcity").append('<option value="' + City.CityID + '">' + City.CityName + '</option>');
            });
```

Comment: Maybe you need to write `$.each(json.City` instead of `$.each(json` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(json.City[0].CityID);​
```

Comment: This Worked.Thanks a lot,i've been trying to solve this for hours.

Comment: Oh nice catch, I forgot to add the array indexing. +1

Answer (score 2):

The data is already parsed when you receive it, you don't need to call `$.parseJSON`. Furthermore, the reason why you are getting a null pointer exception is because `result[0]` doesn't exist: result is an associative array, not a regular array.

```
$.getJSON("handlers/cityhandler.php", function(json){

    console.log(json.City[0].CityID);
});
```

Your second attempt isn't right either; if you're trying to loop over the cities you must loop over the inner array:

```
$.getJSON("handlers/cityhandler.php", function(json){
    $.each(json.City, function(i, val){
        $("#selectcity").append('<option value="' + val.CityID + '">' 
            + val.CityName + '</option>');
    });
});
```

Comment: @tfeseas Yeah I forgot the array indexing in the first block of code. The second one should be working fine though. Also, in general, if you're having trouble with a data structure, try logging small parts of it first like `console.log(json)`, `console.log(json.City)`...and you will quickly realize what is an array and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON output is valid JSON, so the issue is not coming from there. Are you sure that this is exactly what the jQuery handler receives?

Side note, result[0] doesn't exist! Your top element is an object and not an array!

Comment: i receive valid json,i know that but i cannot decode it with jquery.i tried the alternate one too and atleast 10 different ways but still cannot get the values.